# Is reverse prediction possible in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

Is it possible to predict input data by providing output label on a trained model?

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't really make sense.

We use the terms input and output to describe the data w.r.t. the problem we are trying to solve.

For example, given a latitude on the earth's surface, it's possible to create a model to try to predict the average temperature in August. Here the input is the latitude and the output is the avg temperature. So, it is *of course* possible, to try to reverse this and instead frame the problem so as to try to train a model to predict the latitude of a place given it's avg temp in august. BUT in doing so, you have, by definition, changed the input and output around. Latitude is now the output and temp the input.

Comment: So to describe my problem with an example, if I consider "dog" label as an input then is it possible to build a model which can give an image or pixels of it?

Comment: Wait I think I get it now, I just have to train the model inversely, Great!

Comment: But there's a problem, Now I will have different output(slightly changing) based on single label.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
Input 5+2  gives Output 7
Input 6+1 gives Output 7
Input 4+3  gives Output 7.
```

As you see in the example above it is easy given two numbers and an operation to get a number **uniquely**. However starting from number 7 can you **uniquely** predict which were the two numbers that gave 7?
You may run into these sort of problems. However if it is one to one and onto function (bijective), then you might be able to reverse it. Off course you will have to reverse the labels of input and output.